# How do I change the format of a char vector containing milliseconds to timeseries vector in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a DF in R which has two character columns. The first column is a time series array and the second column contains continuous numbers. The time series field has time recorded in milliseconds. I am trying to convert this array to a date array. However whichever method I use to convert the same, I lose the milliseconds information.

Following is the dataframe:

```
time = c("08-08-2016 09:16:33.430","08-08-2016 09:16:37.930")
values <- c(45,21)
my_data <- data.frame(time,values)
```

I would like to preserve the millisecond information. However, as I convert the time char array using following method, I lose the milliseconds (O/P time array= 2016-08-08 09:16:33,08-08-2016 09:16:37) .

```
my_data$time=strptime(my_data$time,format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S.%OS")
```

I also tried using as.POSIXct, as.Date functions but could not resolve. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a standard-enough format so that [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) can parse this automagically with additional input from you:

```
R> timevec <- c("08-08-2016 09:16:33.430","08-08-2016 09:16:37.930")
R> anytime(timevec)
[1] "2016-08-08 09:16:33.43 CDT" "2016-08-08 09:16:37.93 CDT"
R>
```

I tend to have `options(digits.secs=6)` set by default which is why the display also shows the fractional seconds.

Comment: The options(digits.secs=6), was the trick. That solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`%OS` instead of `%S`, not in addition to it. `"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%OS"` is the format string required:

```
options(digits.secs=6)
as.POSIXct(my_data$time, format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%OS")
#[1] "2016-08-08 09:16:33.43 AEST" "2016-08-08 09:16:37.93 AEST"
```